# How to restructure the Web part form Wiki page SPD 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part

I create one wiki page on this page 5 web part created i want to change the location of my web part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi for location of webparts on wikipages can be changed by browser:

1)Edit the page and from ribbon select the select option and point the web part you want to change the location.

2)Select edit source from from ribbon and copy the script and paste in notepad.

3)Repeat the 2nd step for all web parts.

4)And for final paste the script were you want the web part to be on edit source.

Answer (score 0):

Each webparts having `**Webpart Zone index**` property. Using this index you can relocate your webparts within the page.

Edit page--> Edit webpart --> Webpart Property-->Zone index under Layout --> provide index value based on your ordering.

Hope this will help you

Comment: For Wiki page  Webpart Zone index is disabled i can't change this index.

Comment: In the edit mode get the source and make changes.

Comment: Hey bkk  where i get this source code? Site Browser or SharePoint Designer?

Comment: It is disabled on Wiki pages, because its not really a web part zone, but a rich-text editor. However you can move the web parts by using Drag&Drop.Using Designer you can add Zone index https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f82be255-ae1f-42bd-9bac-318b5c6759ff/how-to-add-a-web-part-zone-to-a-wiki-page?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious